# Rails4 + Json API : Increase detail of response

Tags: ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4, grape-api

I'm a newbie on RoR (and Ruby). I need a little help about a json response (with Grape).

This is the sample:

```
    {
      events: [
           {
            'some data':'some data',
             place_id: 1
           }
      ]
    }
```

Now this is the result of `Events.all` in Rails, but I want to make for each event a query for the place, to have more data instead only id. I'm sure that new lambda function can help me, but for now I have no idea about to make it. I'm trying without success...

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

Desired result

```
{
          events: [
               {
                'some data':'some data',
                 place : {
                   id: 1,
                   name: 'Blablabla'
               }
          ]
        }
```

Comment: So you want a function that gives you a list of all the places for a list of events? from where/what service do you want to query it? are you saying that given the place_id you then want to query for the place?

Comment: Exactly... The results that you can see came from Events.all. Now for each event I want to call Place.find(event.place_id), to add more detail about places, for each element of array events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    :events => events.as_json(include: :place)
```

This is a useful for my problem. After add `belongs_to`, obviously.

from http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [ActiveModelSerializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) which allows you to define how your models should be serialized in a manner similar to ActiveRecord DSL (e.g. your problem would be solved by defining that event `has_one :place`)